# Typescript instanceof issue

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code that works, but the moment I change the if to `p instanceof Address` the condition is never met.

`p` is an object but I want to check it against its type that has already been defined:

```
export default class Address {
  public addressLine1: string = ''
  public addressLine2: string | null = null
  public town: string = ''
  public postcode: string = ''
}


  const displayResults = (list: any) => {
    const slicedList = list.slice(0, 3)

    const html = 
      slicedList.map((p: string | Address) => {
        console.log('p: ', p instanceof Address)
        if (typeof p === 'object') {
          return <span key={`id-${uniqid()}`}>{addressToString(p)}</span>
        }
        return <span key={`id-${uniqid()}`}>{p}</span>
      })

    if (list.length > 3) {
      html.push(elipsis)
    }

    return html
  }
```

Comment: What does the `console.log(p instanceof Address)` say?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek always false

Comment: Did you try `console.log(p.constructor.name)`?

Comment: what does `console.log(typeof p)` say?

Comment: If `p` comes from the server or was created as an object literal, `p` will not be an instance of the class even if it has the same fields as the class.

Comment: where `list` comes from? network? So it is likely an object that has the same shape as `Address`, but not created with `new Address`